# understanding return value of some function in Python OpenCV

Tags: python, opencv

I'm having some difficulties understanding return value on some function on Python OpenCV2. For example, I know that `BoundingRect` returns x,y coordinates, width and height, but what I don't know what order and another possible output in `BoundingRect`.

In the OpenCV2 manual, `BoundingRect` and other function such as `contourArea`, `getTrackbarPos`only outputting `retval` which is confusing for me. Can I know the exact order, what data and any other output that might exist?

Comment: It's just `x, y, w, h = cv2.boundingRect(my_contour)`, from http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/dd/d49/tutorial_py_contour_features.html.

Comment: are that documented in OpenCV manual?

Comment: Kind of. For example http://docs.opencv.org/3.1.0/d3/dc0/group__imgproc__shape.html#gacb413ddce8e48ff3ca61ed7cf626a366 shows `boundingRect` with a return value of `Rect`, which is somewhat documented here: http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/basic_structures.html#rect.

Comment: how about another function? like `contourArea` for example